# как поместить изображение на график?

Tags: python, numpy, графика, matplotlib, scipy

скажите пожалуйсте как поместить картинку на график и задать ее положение, спасибо! Я использую pylab

```
pylab.title(filename+' IP=539.1')
pylab.plot(Omega,Sigmatot,color="black",linewidth=0.5) #Plots the real part of the spectrum as a blue curve
#pylab.plot(exen[0],tdm[0],color="red",linewidth=10)
#pylab.ylim(0.0,0.08)
pylab.vlines(exen, tdm,0,linewidth=0.1, color="red", label='Trans. dip. moment [a.u.]')
pylab.xlim(534,539)
pylab.legend()
#pylab.show()
#pylab.savefig(folder + figname) #Saves your figure output
pylab.xlabel('Photon Energy (eV)')
pylab.ylabel('Intensity')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с использованием `matplotlib`:

```
In [23]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg

In [24]: %paste
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = x*np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y, label='y = x * sin(x)')
plt.legend()
ax = plt.gca()

# https://www.echalk.co.uk/Science/physics/solarSystem/InteractiveEarth/images/menuIcons/globeIcons/Terrain.png    
fn = r'D:\download\Terrain.png'

im = plt.imread(fn)

ax.figure.figimage(im,
                   ax.bbox.xmax//2 - im.shape[0]//2,
                   ax.bbox.ymax//2 - im.shape[1]//2,
                   alpha=.25, zorder=1)

## -- End pasted text --
Out[24]: <matplotlib.image.FigureImage at 0xe457fd0>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]